# With Entity Framework, is it useful for optimization to prevent SaveChanges from no-changes client side?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, optimization

In other terms in code languages. And assuming *invoice* is pick from *context*.

**without prevent from no-changes**

```
void updateInvoice(DataBaseEntities context, Invoice invoice, float amount, string currency)
{
  invoice.amount = amount;
  invoice.currency = currency;
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**with prevents from no-changes**

```
void updateInvoice(DataBaseEntities context, Invoice invoice, float amount, string currency)
{
  var needToUpdate = false;

  if ( invoice.amount != amount )
  {
    invoice.amount = amount;
    needToUpdate = true;
  }

  if (invoice.currency != currency)
  {
    invoice.currency = currency;
    needToUpdate = true;
  }

  if (needToUpdate) context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Reality is more about complex database and few hundred thousand records.

What should I prefer to optimize process ?

Comment: I suspect that EF already optimizes for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would optimize nothing. EF tracks changes automatically, and you'll only ever want to turn them *off*.

The Entity Framework does this automatically by keeping a copy of the original data in order to detect what's changed or not. However, since you're asking about optimizations, you should probably read [Performance Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853), specifically the section titled "5 NoTracking Queries".

It is possible to turn off change tracking, and you would have to do what you asked in your original question (assuming in this situation you even would want to do such a thing).

In some cases this might be useful, like inserting a large batch of data, because the change tracking is relatively slow, and the performance gain you get by *turning off* change tracking in this case is *very* significant, on the order of turning multiple minutes into tens of seconds. This case, however, needs no form of change tracking, and so you still wouldn't have to implement your own.

Answer (score 1):

in Entity Framework, the context object keeps an in memory record of the state of the objects it is tracking.  If you call `int numberOfItemsSaved = context.SaveChanges()` it will return the number of objects in an Added, Modified, or Deleted state when SaveChanges was called.  `SaveChanges()` also resets the change tracking info on all the objects, so multiple calls to `SaveChanges()` in the same function will likely show a `0` return value on the second call.

In other words, objects that Entity Framework knows about will not be passed through `SaveChanges()` unless there is an actual change to a Property on the object.